# Removing special characters in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, special-characters

I got a column in a `Dummy` table which had a value `"123"` inserted by mistake.

How should I remove the double quotes from the value in field and have 123 in that field instead.

Help me out

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

You can use T-SQL's `replace` method

> Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.

#### Sample

```
UPDATE Dummy set myColumn = replace(myColumn,'"','')
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
update dummy set your_field = replace(your_field, '"', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
USE [YourDataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [Accounts].[fn_CurrentFeeorArrears]    Script Date: 02/18/2014 12:54:15 ******/
/*****Developed By rameez****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [FN_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER] 
(  
 @INPUT_STRING varchar(max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS 
BEGIN

--declare @testString varchar(max),
DECLARE @NEWSTRING VARCHAR(max) 
-- set @teststring = '$rameez$ali$'
 SET @NEWSTRING = @INPUT_STRING ; 
With SPECIAL_CHARACTER as
(
--SELECT '>' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '<' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '(' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT ')' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '!' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '?' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '@' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '*' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '%' as item
--UNION ALL 
SELECT '$' as item
 )
SELECT @NEWSTRING = Replace(@NEWSTRING, ITEM, '') FROM SPECIAL_CHARACTER  
return @NEWSTRING 
END
select dbo.[FN_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER] ('r$@ameez')
```